# 'unicode' object has no attribute 'saveAsTextFile'

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to modify my file after fetching it from **HDFS** using **pyspark** and then i want to save it in HDFS for that i have written below code.

**Code**:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from pyspark import SparkContext
cat = sc.textFile("/user/root/parsed.txt")
hrk = "@"
for line in cat.collect():
   if (code == "ID"):
      line =line.strip() + "|"+hrk   
      line.saveAsTextFile("/user/root/testsprk")
      print(line)
```

But when i run the code i am getting below error.

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                              
  File "<stdin>", line 30, in <module>
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'saveAsTextFile'
```

I know there is some issue with my **line** variable but i am not able to fix it.

Comment: **`line` is a `unicode` string**. It doesn't have a method `saveAsTextFile` which should be obvious from the error message. Instead open the file for writing and write the string there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It because you are collecting all data, it means that collection is not RDD, but normal list and line is just one string.

You shouldn't collect all data on driver. Instead, use `RDD.map` and then `RDD.saveAsTextFile`

```
def add_hrk_on_id(line):
    if (code == "ID"):
        return line.strip() + "|"+hrk   
    else
        return line

cat.map(add_hrk_on_id).saveAsTextFile(path)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply